# preg_replace match exact word

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to replace words in PHP using preg_replace. When executing the code, it will replace "fuel cap for car" with "cap", as opposed to "auto parts".

```
$string = "fuel cap for car";

$find = array('cap', 'fuel cap for car');
$replace = array('hat', 'auto parts');

echo preg_replace($find, $replace, $string);
```

So, I've already tried a different method. I'm storing the original and replacement values in a database, for example:

Table

> Original: automotive|motorcycle|automobile|car
> parts|piston|motorbike|metal fuel cap for a motorbike
> Replace: AUTO PARTS

> Orignal: cap|baseball cap|hat|beanie
> Replace: HAT

The string being: fuel cap for car.

The code is:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
if(preg_match('/\b'.$row[suggestions].'\b/i', $string)){
$string = $row['description'];
```

But, it's replacing the string with "hat", not "auto parts"

Comment: If you need exact matches, you can use [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace). No need for regular expressions.

Comment: Shouldn't your code first replace `cap` for `hat` leaving you with `fuel hat for car`? Then when it tries to find `fuel cap for car` it will fail leaving your final string as `fuel hat for car`

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

If the `$find` array does not contain too many items, you may solve the problem by creating an associative array from the `$find` and `$replace` arrays, and building a single regex from the array items, namely, a regex containing a single group with all the strings listed as alternatives, and then, upon finding match, replace with the corresponding `$replace` value.

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/NIvpqE):

```php
$string = "fuel cap for car";

$find = array('cap', 'fuel cap for car');
$replace = array('hat', 'auto parts');
$arr = array_combine($find, $replace);
usort($find, function($a, $b) {          // Longer phrases must come first
    return strlen($b) - strlen($a);
});

echo preg_replace_callback('~\b(?:' . implode('|', $find) . ')\b~', function($x) use ($arr) {
    return $arr[$x[0]];
}, $string);
// => auto parts
```